# A method to get a document's path

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called `Document`, in this I have a method that I use throughout my website to get the full path to the specific document:

```php
public function getDocument($documentName = true)
{
    $documentName = $documentName ? $this->name : null;

    return storage_path('app/' . $this->getPath() . $documentName);
}

public function getPath()
{
    return "{$this->stream->token}/{$this->unique_id}/";
}
```

I use it like this (example):

```php
$documentPath = $this->document->getDocument();
```

However, as you can see, the document path is made up of:

```
$this->stream->token/$this->unique_id/
```

Where `$this->stream->token` is calling a relationship in my Document model.

```php
public function stream()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
}
```

Now the method works - I can use the `getDocument()` to get the full path to the actual file (or just the folder, if I pass in `false`).

However, this code is called from multiple places at different times - and because the folder structure is dependent on the `stream_token`, it makes a query to get the associated stream on each request.

## Solution(s)?

I have tried adding a `$with = ['stream']` property to my Document model, so  the associated stream is always loaded when fetching the model - but this I don't believe is a good option either, since then all the other queries I have for the document model, that don't care about the stream property make an extra query.

What else can I do to improve the method and keep the # of queries to the database to a minimum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, this is not an answer to your question, but it is a partial review of your code.

It seems you've got a serious problem with choosing your names. They don't actually tell me what the purpose of the methods is, or the content of the variables.

Your method `getDocument()` can do two things: Return the path or the folder of the document. The name doesn't tell me that. It should be something like `getDocumentPathOrFolder()`. The argument `$documentName` doesn't contain a document name. It's a boolean. The only way to find out, what really is contained in this argument, is to read the code in the method. It seems to decide whether a path or folder should be returned. A better name would have been `$addNameToFolder`. Still not ideal.

To make matters worse you have a method called `getPath()` which, you've guessed it, doesn't return a path. By now I no idea what is actually returned by this method.

If I'm allowed to completely rewrite your code, with a better structure and better names, it would look something like this:

```
class Document 
{

    public function getDocumentName()
    {
        return $this->documentName;
    }

    public function getDocumentFolder()
    {
        return storage_path("app/{$this->stream->token}/{$this->unique_id}/"); 
    }

    public function getDocumentPath()
    { 
        return $this->getDocumentFolder() . $this->getDocumentName();
    }

}
```

I assume that `storage_path()` is part of Laravel, and cannot be changed. The long argument to `storage_path()` should probably be split into its seperate parts, especially if you also use it elsewhere, but please, spent some time to choose good names.

References:

[Ten tips to help you choose good names](http://carlosschults.net/en/how-to-choose-good-names)

[Writing Good Method & Variable Names](https://dev.to/rachelsoderberg/writing-good-method-variable-names-47il)

[The importance of naming in programming](https://carlalexander.ca/importance-naming-programming/)